# How to read .rtf File from URL in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview, rtf, readfile

My app needs to read .rtf file from URL. I am going to read it as

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.rtf",_URL]];
    NSError* error;
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

Now when I load this text in UITextView. It gives me tags with { and / characters with the original file text. Please guide me that how can i read the right text which did not include any brackets and html data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.rtf file always contains Tags with itself for formating text color alignment and other properties..

please open that .rtf file in to text edit and convert all text part of that file to  simple text.

then your existing code will work.

else instead of taking the UItextView open it in UIWebview.

hope it will be helpfull for you.

Comment: NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.test.com/test.rtf"];
 NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 [webView loadRequest:req]; It is working in Webview. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use RTF in a UITextView by first transforming it into an NSAttributedString and then setting the value of the UITextView's attributedString property to the NSAttributedString.

```
NSAttributedString *stringWithRTF = [[NSAttributedString alloc]   initWithFileURL:rtfDoc options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSRTFTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

// Instantiate UITextView object
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];

textView.attributedText=stringWithRTF;

[self.view addSubview:textView];
```