# Parse RTF in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, rtf

I want to parse RTF file in Objective c.Is its possible to parse it? if is possible then how can I use it into IOS.I want all the text and formatting.
I have tried in so many way to get text and formatting for this purpose I have used UIWEBVIEW but its not return any text string

```
NSURL *imgPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"test" withExtension:@"rtf"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgPath];
[webView loadData:data MIMEType:@"text/rtf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"/"]];
 NSString *html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.innerHTML"];
```

Here html return nil value.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe these will be of help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501240/ios-objective-c-display-rtf-document and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686381/how-to-read-rtf-file-from-url-in-iphone-app

Comment: @Da_smokes Yes I am doing in the same way but the issue is I want extract text and formatting from RTF

Comment: if test.rtf is in your app (the path is in the mainBundle) why are you using a webview? try converting the data to an nsstring with [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]

Comment: @gg13 Yes I can get the text by using [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] but the issue is when I am going to edit the RTF then how to edit it

Comment: ...well you'll have the contents of the RTF that way and you can edit it as you please

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this question is very old but in case someone stumbles across this problem:

The `html` is nil as the `webView` is not finished loading. Fetch the html in the `UIWebViewDelegate`:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString *html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.innerHTML"];

    NSLog(@"Html: %@",html);

}
```

You will get the desired html.